# Spring security session management is not working

Tags: spring, spring-security

After I successfully login when I try to login with another browser It redirects me to authentication-failure-url. Why it doesn't redirect to expired-url?

```
<http auto-config='false' use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>        
<intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>
<logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>        
<form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"                                                       
            default-target-url="/pages/index.xhtml"
            always-use-default-target="true"                                                                            
            authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?error=true"/>
<custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="customAjaxControlFilter" />
<session-management invalid-session-url="/login.xhtml?error=sessionExpired" session-authentication-error-url="/login.xhtml?error=alreadyLogin">
        <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login.xhtml?error=expired"/>            
</session-management>
```

**EDIT:** By the way, After I successfully logout it redirects me to invalid-session-url. I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: Please read [this section of the manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-session-mgmt) :).

Comment: @LukeTaylor Not about my problem. I checked and It deletes cookies successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour. From the manual:

> The second login will then be rejected. By “rejected”, we mean that the user will be sent to the authentication-failure-url if form-based login is being used.

This is what happens if you set `error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"`.

The [`expired-url`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-concurrency-control) parameter is used if you haven't set `error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"`. In that case, the new login will be allowed, the original session will be marked as expired and if you try to use it, you will be redirected to this URL.

Comment: Now when I try to login with second browser It works but original session(first browser) just frozen. Also I can access pages with first browser.

Comment: You don't appear to have any protected resources in your configuration, so there's nothing to stop you accessing pages.

Comment: I have but I didn't write them to question because there are too many. like <intercept-url pattern="/coworkers/*" access="hasAnyRole('superadmin','admin')" /> .I have found that It also checks session at Login page.

Comment: You'll need to debug the request. It could be a lot of things - the browser cache, for example. I'm not sure what you mean by "it also checks session at login page".